# create bounding meshes that have box shape

Tags: python, modifiers

i have a mesh, 
i want to create bounding meshes that have box/convex shape that bounds around that mesh as close as possible
in other way, my question is
How to split a mesh into other sub meshes that have box/convex shape (by python scripting,modifiers) ... (or create an additional box that bound the mesh)

(for who interested in, my goal is : i want to create mesh convex collider to object in unity,because from unity 5.0 does not accept mesh collider with rigidbody, we have to use convex mesh collider ,but the convex mesh not bound good,there are spaces that have collider (while it shouldn't )
Thanks alot

Comment: What's your actual goal? Please add more detail to your question. There already is a bounding box per object *(Object Data > Display > Bounds)*, which is related to the dimensions of the object. The concept of a [Convex Hulls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) might be interesting for you as well.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i added more detail, but the object data bound not fit the mesh ,therefore it does not create the actual mesh.About the convex , is it possible to split the mesh into convex meshes / objects ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think, if i understand what correctly what you are asking, you should maybe try the remesh modifier set to "Blocks".

The effect will be the following:

[image]

You can adjust the depth and scale to get different size blocks.